# Repeating headers in Non-Blocking Retry Mechanism - Spring Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka [non-blocking retry mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic). I've noticed that the following headers accumulate on next retry topics:

```
retry_topic-attempts
retry_topic-backoff-timestamp
retry_topic-original-timestamp
```

It means that on retry_0 there are 3 headers, on retry_1 they are doubled and finally on dlt they are tripled.

As far as I unterstand they are essential to conduct retry process, but I don't think that DLT needs information regarding retry_0.

Is it possible not to do it, because the messages become heavier and heavier with each retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka headers allow multiple values; starting with version 2.9.5, you can configure the framework to replace headers instead of adding values to them.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2529

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.9.5/reference/html/#retry-headers

Please open an issue on GitHub, we should add an option similar to `stripOriginalExceptionHeaders` (which is true by default) for these other headers.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I created an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2549